# Load Operation failed for query 'QueryName ' . The remote server returned an error : not found

Tags: c#, iis, wcf-ria-services

I published a Silverlight application with WCF RIA service to my local host on Windows 10 (IIS7).

The application is working just fine.

When opening a specific screen, I get this error:

> Load operation failed for query 'QueryName ' - the remote server returned an error: not found

I have made a lot of searches. I am pretty sure that the problem because the size of information retrieved from the query. I have increased the default size of the IIS, and I have used this field in the web.config file:

```
maxItemsInObjectGraph = "2147483647"
```

But the error still appears.

Can anyone suggest how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is your `connectionStrings` in the `Web.config` and `App.config` are correct? 
Make sure your web.config has

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
```

inside `<system.serviceModel>`
and 
`<add name="DomainServiceModule" type="System.Web.Ria.Services.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.Web.Ria, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />`
inside `<httpModules>`.

There is probably some error happening which comes back as NotFound. Also, make sure you've enabled Silverlight debugging in the properties of the website project.

Give it a last try(make these changes to the root web.config):

```
<system.webServer>
<security>
<authentication>
<basicAuthentication enabled="false" />
</authentication>
</security>
</system.webServer>
```

Hope it helps!